# Why is the %A specifier in F#'s printf non-existent in OCaml's printf?

Tags: f#, ocaml

In F#'s `printf` there is the format specifier `%A` which enables to pass in any F# type, and it would be evaluated and printed.

As an example:

```
type Result<'a> =
    | Failure
    | Success of 'a       

printf "%A" (Success "hello") // prints out 'Success "hello"'
```

Where, clearly, `Result<'a>` isn't a built-in type.

I can declare a similar type in OCaml, but there is no equivalent specifier for `Printf.printf` - instead, I would have to implement my own `string_of_result` function, and use the `%s` specifier in the format string. Moreover, since this is a polymorphic type, I would have to create a not-straightforward function that can handle any type instance of `'a`.

My question is - why does OCaml lack this handy specifier? Is it because there is no incentive to implement it? Is it because there's some lacking under-the-hood mojo, which is just there in F#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say "lacking under-the-hood mojo" is probably the reason.

In F#, `%A` specifier defers printing to a reflection-based printer - it uses runtime type information to traverse and print the value. The reflection API used in that process is very much a .NET-specific thing. Also while handy, it's also a comparatively expensive mechanism - it shouldn't be used as a blanket specifier if you can use a more concrete one.

From what I know, OCaml doesn't have corresponding reflection capabilities that could be used here. Perhaps there's another mechanism that would let you implement a generic print - but I'm not familiar enough with OCaml internals to tell.

Answer (score 7):

The usual way to do this in OCaml is to use the `%a` specifier, and write (or derive) a printer for `result` to pass to it.

That might look like this:

```
type 'a result =
  | Success of 'a
  | Failure
[@@deriving show]

Format.printf "%a" (pp_result Format.pp_print_string) (Success "hello")
```

where `pp_result` has been generated by the `deriving` clause. Note that `pp_result` takes a formatting function as an argument which it uses to print any `'a`s.

OCaml erases types (almost) completely during compilation, so reflection cannot be used to implement an automagical printing function as in F#. It's not clear that reflection would work well in a language with abstract types, anyway.

Comment: Just as an addition: this solution needs processing by ppx - when I just copy & paste the code to the REPL, ```pp_result``` is still undefined.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x - I noticed it too. For some reason I already had `ppx_deriving` installed via `opam`, but now an error is thrown: `Cannot locate deriver show`.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to complicate an answer that is really about `printf` specifiers with details of building/configuring `ppx_deriving`. (For reference: in the toplevel, `#use "topfind"` and then `#require "ppx_deriving.show"`. But see the `ppx_deriving` docs for the details.)